# jquery multiple url replace regex

Tags: jquery, regex, url

Simply, I want to parse URL link(s) and add html reference using jQuery, RegEx.

Source HTML is:

```
<div id="test"> my favorite search engines are http://www.google.com 
    and http://stackoverflow.com Do you agree? </div>
```

My Current Script is:

```
var exp = /(^|[^'">])((ftp|http|https):\/\/(\S+))(\b|$)/gi;
$('#test').html($('#test').html().replace(exp,
    "&nbsp;<a href='$2' target='_blank'><img src='go.gif'/></a>"));
});
```

And its result is as following:

```
<div id="test"> my favorite search engines are 
<a href="http://www.google.com" target='_blank'>
<img src='go.gif'/></a> and
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target='_blank'>
<img src='go.gif'/></a>
Do you agree? </div>
```

I know this script just replaces and can't preserve its source.
I'd like to add its original URL right after 'img tag'.
Anyone has an idea to get following result?

```
<div id="test"> my favorite search engines are 
<a href="http://www.google.com" target='_blank'>
<img src='go.gif'/>http://www.google.com</a> and
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target='_blank'>
<img src='go.gif'/>http://stackoverflow.com</a>
Do you agree? </div>
```

Thank you for your comment in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution (you can test the regular expression here: http://regexr.com/)

```
var test = $('#test'),
    txt = test.html(),
    pattern = /((?:http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(?:\.[\w\-_]+)+(?:[\w\-\.,@?^=%&:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&/~\+#])?)/gi;

test.html(txt.replace(pattern, '<a href="$1" target="_blank"><img src="go.gif"/>$1</a>'));
```

You can add some css:

```
#test a img { margin-right: 5px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var urlRE = /(^|[^'">])((ftp|http|https):\/\/(\S+))(\b|$)/gi;
var $test = $('#test');
var text = $test.text();

text = text.replace(urlRE, "<a href=\"$&\">$&</a>");

$test.html(text);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zQBSm/)

Comment: Truly appreciate for your right & light speed answer!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $('#test').html($('#test').replace(regex, "a href=" ????));
> //              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

won't work. You would need `….html($('#test').html().replace(…`, but it's better to use the [callback version of `.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-functionindex--oldhtml).

For the regex we'll just use "*anything that starts with `http://`*", you're free to refine that.

For the replacement, we could add an extra [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) around the url, but we don't really need this to use a [replacement pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter).

```
var regex = /http:\/\/\S+/g;
$('#test').html(function(i, markup) {
    return markup.replace(regex, '<a href="$&">$&</a>');
});
```

---

Oh, the question has changed substantially.

> I know this script just replaces and can't preserve its source. I'd like to add its original URL right after 'img tag'.

You can just use the `$2` replacement pattern twice. Btw, you just removed the first capturing group entirely and put `&nbsp;` instead, which can be incorrect. Better use

```
"$1<a href='$2' target='_blank'><img src='go.gif'/>$2</a>"
```